# Is there any procedure for update Live server

Tags: server, webserver, updatedb

Can someone send me a document with standard procedure for updating LIVE Server.
Is there such thing? We make the updates to our system once per week, but we are not sure if there is some specification how and when should be done.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand the question? Are you asking what are the "best practices" for updating a live, production server? I guess you could do this using cronjobs that run every night, outside working hours. Maybe you can read [this](http://serverfault.com/q/159750) question; it's similar to yours but the concern is over updating the website itself. It's a good read.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there such thing?

No, simply because every situation is different.

---

What -we- do (we are hosting our software on our own servers in a datacenter and we also have in-house servers where we host our own software and we have servers locally at our clients (but those we do not need to maintain)) ...

We have 2 servers and call them "live1" and "live2". Data between the 2 is synched real time (MySQL data replication). Clients work on "live1" and "live2" is the fail safe. So if "live1" fails "live2" kicks in automatically. Users are also silently redirected to "live2" is this one becomes active.

During an update/upgrade fase "live2" gets disconnected and our clients get notified that the fail safe server is out for the next few hours. We then make an extra backup of "live2".

"live2" gets all the updates and we check "live2" for obvious/critical problems (updates for us means system updates (Ubuntu) but also our own software). If no critical problems occur "live2" becomes "live1", "live1" becomes "live2" (we do that when there is a low amount of people active on the system; so around 17:00, 18:00).

After that we update the new "live2" server and reconnect it as the fail safe. And the data is then synched.

And then we wait for the next update cycle.

---

If you need the servers up and running 5 days a week you could update/upgrade on a Friday evening, Saturday or Sunday without any client noticing and with plenty room if all failed and you need to restore from a backup. If so, then our method is serious overkill but our software is used world wide so we strive for a 100% up-time.